# Aggregate multiple objects as an array and synchronize changes

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I start to use a third party `<datetime-picker>` component that only accept a `Date[]` of size 2 as its `v-model` (for a range of time). In my previous codebase, I maintained 2 separate `Date` objects, i.e. `startTime` and `endTime`, and I hope to stick with that.

```js
// in previous codebase (class-based Vue component)
private startTime = new Date();
private endTime = new Date();

// now I must use an array due to the third-party component...
private dateTimeRange = [this.startTime, this.endTime];
```

Apparently the following won't work, since the reference itself in the array will be overwritten:

```html
<datetime-picker v-model="dateTimeRange" ... />
```

I want a clean way to propagate changes (issued by the datetime picker component) to the array *back* to `startTime` and `endTime` object.

Comment: What library do you use? Is there an error?

Comment: @sandrooco I'm using element-ui based on Vue2, but I think the answer might be framework-agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try it like this:

1. `private dateTimeRange = [new Date(), new Date()];` --> to remove the more complicated reference stuff through a "proxy" instance variable.
2. Use a `computed`/property accessor to then receive and render both values:

   ```
   private get dateRange(): NiceType {
       return {start: this.dateTimeRange[0], end: this.dateTimeRange[0]}
   }
   ```

Comment: @SedriX could you try it out? Did it work?

Comment: works like a charm! thanks